# Individual point-sizing in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matlab, plot, matplotlib

I'd like to have non-uniform point sizes in matplotlib (set a size for each point). Is there a way to do this? I guess I could hack it by having a separate plot command (with markersize set) for each point, but that would be really annoying. Is there a more principled way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found out that you can use `scatter` for this:

```
  scatter(500:600,600:700,1:101);
```

where the format is: `scatter(x,y,sizes,markerType)`

Produces:

[image]

Comment: This code didn't run for me, but I did have success with `scatter(range(500,600),range(600,700),range(1,101),marker='o',facecolors='none')`

Comment: This might be a Matlab version issue.

Comment: FWIW the question is about matplotlib (not matlab), though I see that one of the tags is matlab.