# How to change color of cluster points in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am implementing AP clustering algorithm. I don't know how to assign different colors to different cluster points.

My code segment is:

```
    I=find(diag(E)>0) %  Find number of cluster head
    K=length(I); %cluster head
    fprintf('Number_of_clusters:''%d',length(I))
    [tmp c]=max(distance(:,I),[],2);
    c(I)=1:K ;              
    idx=I(c)
    for k=1:K
    ii=find(c==k)% cluster points
    end;
```

I have to set a different color to different cluster members like red for cluster one, blue for second one and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're not doing any plotting, so where do you want to set colors?

Comment: You might consider using [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html) [like in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7692174/677667).  Specifically you can change the marker type programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example for how to plot one cluster in red dots and one in green plus signs:

```
n = 100;
cluster1 = randn([n,2]); % 100 2-D coordinates 
cluster2 = randn([n,2]); % 100 2-D coordinates 
hold on
plot(cluster1(:,1),cluster1(:,2),'r.'); %plotting cluster 1 pts
plot(cluster2(:,1),cluster2(:,2),'g+'); %plotting cluster 2 pts
```

[image]

Now just get your data into the same form as `cluster1` and `cluster 2` (matrices of the points in cluster 1 and cluster 2) and then you can plot them.

Let's say you don't have a fixed number of clusters. Then you can do this:

```
%Defines some order of colors/symbols
symbs = {'r.', 'g+','m*','b.','ko','y+'}; 

figure(1)
hold on
for i = 1:num_clusters,
   % Some code here to extract the coordinates in one particular cluster...
   plot(cluster(:,1),cluster(:,2),symbs{i});
end
```

Use this link on [colorspec](http://mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html) from petrichor's comment to learn about all the different combinations of symbols/colors you can define.

Comment: But number of Clusters are not fixed.

Comment: @user1416605 You can modify your code accordingly. After you "hold on" you can plot any number of clusters you like. To set the color programmaticaly, see here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colorspec.html

Comment: @user1416605 okay, the solution is modified to show you how to deal with a variable number of clusters. Thanks a bunch to petrichor for making this solution better. :)